# Python Selenium / Behave (BDD) and behave context longevity

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-behave

I am new to Selenium / Behave and trying to put a basic test together. My folder structure, within my main project folder, includes:

- features/steps (feature files / python steps code):
  login.feature
  steps/login.py
- pages (page class.py files):
  login.py
  home.py
- lib (includes a utility package)
- screenshots ...

So for each page that I process, I create an object within my steps file. The page associated object has page specific methods and property references.

I have successfully gotten a login scenario working. However after I add a second scenario to the feature file, the problem begins. So here is what I have in my login.feature file:

```
Feature: Front Office Registration Login

  Scenario: Login to Patient registration with valid parameters
  Given a user launches a browser
  When the user navigate to the Front Office Registration Login page
  And enters a valid username
  And enters a valid password
  And clicks on Login button
  Then user must be taken to the landing page


  Scenario: Attempt to login to Patient registration with invalid parameters
  Given the user navigates to the Front Office Registration Login page
  When enters an invalid username
  And enters a password
  And clicks on Login button
  Then an invalid credentials message must be displayed
```

The first step of my first scenario, includes the creation of my login_page object and attaches it to the behave context:

```
from behave import *
from pages.login import LoginPage
from pages.home import HomePage
from selenium import webdriver
from lib import ohaitestutl as ohai


@given('a user launches a browser')
def launch_browser(context):
    context.driver = webdriver.Edge()
    # Instantiate our page(s)
    context.login_page = LoginPage(driver=context.driver)
    context.home_page = HomePage(driver=context.driver)


@when('the user navigate to the Front Office Registration Login page')
def navigate_to_login(context):
    status = context.login_page.goto_login_page()
    if status != 'ok':
        context. self.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'navigate_to_login.png')
    assert status == 'ok'


@when('enters a valid username')
def enter_username(context):
    status = context.login_page.set_username()
    assert status == 'ok'


@when('enters a valid password')
def enter_valid_password(context):
    status = context.login_page.set_password()
    if status != 'ok':
        context. self.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'enter_valid_password.png')
    assert status == 'ok'


@when('clicks on Login button')
def click_login_button(context):
    status = context.login_page.click_login()
    if status != 'ok':
        context. self.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'click_login_button.png')
    assert status == 'ok'


@then('user must be taken to the landing page')
def verify_home_page(context):
    status = context.home_page.verify_home_page()
    import time
    if status != 'ok':
        context.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'verify_home_page.png')
    assert status == 'ok'


@given('the user navigates to the Front Office Registration Login page')
def navigate_to_login_page(context):
    status = context.login_page.goto_login_page()
    if status != 'ok':
        context. self.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'navigate_to_login.png')
    assert status == 'ok'


@when('enters an invalid username')
def set_invalid_username(context):
    """Enter an invalid username."""
    status = context.login_page.set_invalid_username()
    if status != 'ok':
        context.self.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'set_invalid_username.png')
    assert status == 'ok'



@when('enters a password')
def enter_password_invalid(context):
    """Enter a password for an invalid user account."""
    status = context.login_page.set_password()
    if status != 'ok':
        context.self.driver.save_screenshot(ohai.SCREENSHOTS_DIR / 'enter_password.png')
    assert status == 'ok'


@then('an invalid credentials message must be displayed')
def check_for_error_message(context):
    status = context.login_page.check_invalid_creds_message()
```

The problem is that by the time I hit the second scenario, it is behaving as though the login_page is lost from the context:

```
  Scenario: Attempt to login to Patient registration with invalid parameters  # features/test.feature:9
    Given the user navigates to the Front Office Registration Login page      # features/steps/login.py:55
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Development\PycharmProjects\foreg_test\venv\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 1329, in run
          match.run(runner.context)
        File "C:\Development\PycharmProjects\foreg_test\venv\lib\site-packages\behave\matchers.py", line 98, in run
          self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
        File "features\steps\login.py", line 57, in navigate_to_login_page
          status = context.login_page.goto_login_page()
        File "C:\Development\PycharmProjects\foreg_test\venv\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 321, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(msg)
      AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'login_page'
```

Is this expected behaviour? I was hoping that I could use the same browser session to string together a couple of scenarios, but on the face of it, I'm not sure that it will allow it. It's as though the Context object is getting reset with the `@given` decorator function.

UPDATE:
I have found a kind of workaround, using the "Background", feature file option. This allows me to specify the browser launch and login options as common steps. This does still launch new sessions for each scenario. I am wondering if this is the general approach taken.

Thanks,

Clive

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what the general approach for Selenium with Behave is, I can give you my approach. I'm using the [SeleniumBase Behave integration](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/ReadMe.md) for `selenium` tests that run with `behave`. Here's a sample .feature file for that:

```
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the Swag Labs App

  Background:
    Given Open the Swag Labs Login Page

  Scenario: User can log in and log out successfully
    When Login to Swag Labs with standard_user
    Then Verify that the current user is logged in
    When Logout from Swag Labs
    Then Verify on Login page

  Scenario: User can order a backpack from the store
    When Login to Swag Labs with standard_user
    Then Verify that the current user is logged in
    And Save price of "Backpack" to <item_price>
    When Add "Backpack" to Cart
    Then Verify shopping cart badge shows 1 item(s)
    When Click on shopping cart icon
    And Click Checkout
    And Enter checkout info: First, Last, 12345
    And Click Continue
    Then Verify 1 "Backpack"(s) in cart
    And Verify cost of "Backpack" is <item_price>
    And Verify item total is $29.99
    And Verify tax amount is $2.40
    And Verify total cost is $32.39
    When Click Finish
    Then Verify order complete
    When Logout from Swag Labs
    Then Verify on Login page
```

Here's another one:

```
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the Calculator App

  Background:
    Given Open the Calculator App

  Scenario: Pressing "C" outputs "0"
    When Press C
    Then Verify output is "0"

  Scenario: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
    When Press C
    And Press 1
    And Press +
    And Press 2
    And Press +
    And Press 3
    And Press +
    And Press 4
    And Press +
    And Press 5
    Then Verify output is "1+2+3+4+5"
    When Press =
    Then Verify output is "15"
```

Here's part of a "steps" file:

```py
from behave import step

@step("Open the Calculator App")
def go_to_calculator(context):
    context.sb.open("https://seleniumbase.io/apps/calculator")

@step("Press C")
def press_c(context):
    context.sb.click("button#clear")

@step("Press (")
def press_open_paren(context):
    context.sb.click('button[id="("]')

@step("Press )")
def press_close_paren(context):
    context.sb.click('button[id=")"]')

@step("Press ÷")
def press_divide(context):
    context.sb.click("button#divide")

@step("Press ×")
def press_multiply(context):
    context.sb.click("button#multiply")

@step("Press -")
def press_subtract(context):
    context.sb.click("button#subtract")

@step("Press +")
def press_add(context):
    context.sb.click("button#add")

@step("Press =")
def press_equal(context):
    context.sb.click("button#equal")

@step("Press 1")
def press_1(context):
    context.sb.click('button[id="1"]')

@step("Press 2")
def press_2(context):
    context.sb.click('button[id="2"]')

# ...
```

SeleniumBase also has other useful tools for `behave`, such as dashboards, GUI Apps, test generators, etc. More info here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/examples/behave_bdd

Comment: Hi @MichaelMintz. Thanks fo rthe reply. I was specificaly interested in hhow the browser session object is shared and whether using Background was the only way to prevent the error encountered.